# Is source source_wildcard-mask necessary when traffic is orginating from a VLAN when access list is applied in direction of the interface (in)

Tags: vlan

Let's say I have a vlan 1 with domain 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255...also a vlan 2 with 192.168.20.0. 0.0.0.255..These are connected to router with intervlan enabled. Now I want to implement access list with ip-access group in...Since the traffic is checked when leaving the vlan in direction to the interface, can I use permit TCP any destination destination_wildcard-mask instead of TCP source source_wildcard-mask destination destination_wildcard-mask? Since every traffic leaving the network must originate from within that network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since the traffic is checked when leaving the vlan in direction to the
> interface, can I use permit TCP any destination
> destination_wildcard-mask instead of TCP source source_wildcard-mask
> destination destination_wildcard-mask?

Yes. The `any` keyword is translated to `0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255`, and it literally means any address. Using `any` as the source means that the effect is any source address (even spoofed source addresses, which are possible from hosts on your VLAN, regardless of the network addressing on that VLAN) will match the ACL source address.

---

Cisco has a document that explains ACLs: *[Configure and Filter IP Access Lists](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/ios-firewall/23602-confaccesslists.html)*.